# Having two braces which refer to a set of equations and its initial conditions on the same line

Tags: equations, positioning

Say I have;

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
     \dot x = 2z + xy \\
     \dot y  = 4xy - z\\
     \dot z = -5z
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

  \begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
     x(0) = 0 \\
     y(0)  = 0\\
     z(0) = 1
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
```

How would I write this so that both equations are on the same line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the two `cases` in the same `equation` environment, separating them using something like `\quad`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    \dot{x} = 2z + xy \\
    \dot{y} = 4xy - z \\
    \dot{z} = -5z
  \end{cases}
  \qquad
  \begin{cases}
    x(0) = 0 \\
    y(0) = 0 \\
    z(0) = 1
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Remember to not leave a blank line in `equation`.

Comment: Thanks! Just one additional thing... If I want to put "such that" between the two equations how would I do this?

Comment: @mrhappysmile: You can use `\quad \text{such that} \quad` (and adjust the spacing to suit your needs). Some people might prefer using `\text{ such that }` (note the spaces).

Comment: Sorry Werner, what is required to do something that includes both text and maths say;\quad \text{is} x_\geq \quad EDIT: Nevermind that works...

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possible solutions.

[image]

If you want the second version, @Werner's answer is much better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
     \dot x = 2z + xy  &     x(0) = 0 \\
     \dot y  = 4xy - z &     y(0)  = 0\\
     \dot z = -5z      &     z(0) = 1
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
  \begin{equation} \notag
    \begin{cases}
     \dot x = 2z + xy \\
     \dot y  = 4xy - z\\
     \dot z = -5z
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
     x(0) = 0 \\
     y(0)  = 0\\
     z(0) = 1
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```